# How to mount NTFS in Linux without root password

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs

I want to mount/umount a 3rd hard disk (with a NTFS filesystem) under Linux (OpenSuse (Leap15.2)) only as needed and as a normal user. But without entering my root password every time. So far I have tried it with entries in the fstab and in sudoers, but each time I must type the root password. Below are the entries in fstab and sudoers:

```
in sudoers:

root    ALL = (ALL) ALL
ALL     ALL = (ALL) ALL
#
%users  ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/mount
%users  ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/umount

in fstab:

LABEL=DATA3 /home/leap153/data3  ntfs-3g noauto,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=002,fmask=002,noatime  0 0
```

FUSE is installed and uid and gid have the correct number of the user (checked).

Comment: What command you try to execute with `sudo`?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with NTFS-mounts, but are you able to add any other commands using NOPASSWD to sudoers and run them passwordless? Did you edit the file with `visudo` if that's applicable on OpenSuse?

Comment: Maybe also check out Systemd automounting. It is flexible and just works – if you use systemd anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it by configuring sudo to allow mount, this is highly insecure.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/258637/why-do-i-need-the-root-password-when-mounting-an-internal-drive-in-linux for details.

Instead, try adding the user option in fstab and then use mount without sudo.  Note that this only works with kernel 5.15 and later and the new ntfs3 driver:

```
 LABEL=DATA3 /home/leap153/data3  ntfs3 noauto,user,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=002,fmask=002,noatime  0 0
```

Then

```
 mount /home/leap153/data3
```

Another alternative is to use autofs or possibly udisks.

Unfortuantely, udisks doesn't work with volume labels, so you will need to determine the real block device for the partition.  You can use the `blkid -L data3` command to find it.  For example

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1
```

which likely will mount your partition (it will tell you where) as /media/user/DATA3 (where user is your username).  Note that this will only work without sudo for the user logged into the console.

The third alternative using autofs is more automatic but also more complicated to set up, but will work for all users, both local and remote.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: in terminal I do this `sudo mount /home/leap153/data3` and it works with entered password
@sampi: 1) yes, visudo is present in Suse, but I edited sudoers directly as root with vi. Does that make a difference? 
2)Yes, I tried `VERACRYPT` in sudoers because it also constantly asks for the root password (and removed again because it did not work).

Comment: despite `user` entry and reboot the problem remains unchanged. However, I get the following message: _Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE
library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated
FUSE support and make it setuid root. Please see more information at
http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged_

Comment: What kernel version are you using?  Might be able to use something other than ntfs-3g.  Otherwise autofs or udisks is a better bet.

Comment: Updated answer with more details why this didn't work and alternatives.

Comment: blkid can be used to "resolve" label / uuid btw

Comment: thanks, I can never remember blkid

Comment: First of all a thank you to all! But I believe more and more that the real problem is OPENSUSE itself. I fear that the "Suse people" have built in some restrictions to make the system particularly secure (which is not bad in principle). I don't understand e.g. why the solution with 'sudoers' generally doesn't work or what this 'FUSE' works or possibly has to be configured. It would be good to know if my entries in 'fstab' or 'sudoers' work like this in other distros.

Comment: The sudoers entry might work, but it is insecure and shouldn't be used, I'll add a link to why.  Both fuse and ntfs-3g are just special, so I didn't know that wouldn't work but it doesn't surprise me, and it probably isn't a SUSE thing.